# Retrieving data from an API using Blazor. Data not being pulled

Tags: api, asp.net-core, crud, blazor

Using ASP.net Core 3.0 and Blazor. I am modifying the project found here: https://ankitsharmablogs.com/asp-net-core-crud-using-blazor-and-entity-framework-core/

I used Scofold-DbContext to build my Context file and the Model class. VS had no issue contacting the Database to create the required files.

Razor View:

```
@using ShopLive1.Shared.Models
@page "/fetchemployees"
@inject  HttpClient Http

<h1>Shop Live - Repair Order Update</h1>

@if(roList == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading....</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Control Number</th>
                <th>VIN</th>
                <th>Make</th>
                <th>Model</th>
                <th>Customer</th>
                <th>Repair Stage</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>Assigned</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach(var ro in roList)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@ro.ControlNumber</td>
                    <td>@ro.Vin</td>
                    <td>@ro.Make</td>
                    <td>@ro.Model</td>
                    <td>@ro.Customer</td>
                    <td>@ro.Stage</td>
                    <td>@ro.VehicleLocation</td>
                    <td>@ro.Technician</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}


@functions{
    RepairOrder[] roList;

    protected override async Task OnInitAsync()
    {
        roList = await Http.GetJsonAsync<RepairOrder[]>("api/RepairOrder/Index");
    }
}
```

Data Access layer class:

```
ShopLiveContext db = new ShopLiveContext();

        //To get all repair orders
        public List<RepairOrder> GetAllRepairOrders()
        {
            try
            {
                return db.RepairOrder.ToList();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }

        }

        //To add new Repair Orders
        public void AddRepairOrder(RepairOrder ro)
        {
            try
            {
                db.RepairOrder.Add(ro);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        //To update Repair Orders
        public void UpdateRepairOrder(RepairOrder ro)
        {
            try
            {
                db.Entry(ro).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        //Get the details of a particular RO
        public RepairOrder GetRepairOrderDetails(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                RepairOrder ro = db.RepairOrder.Find(id);
                return ro;
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        //To delete a record
        public void DeleteRepairOrder(int id)
        {
            try
            {
                RepairOrder ro = db.RepairOrder.Find(id);
                db.RepairOrder.Remove(ro);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Data context file:

```
public ShopLiveContext()
        {
        }

        public ShopLiveContext(DbContextOptions<ShopLiveContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<RepairOrder> RepairOrder { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
            {
                optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=sumcso-8g5lr52;Initial Catalog=ShopLive;Integrated Security=True");
            }
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.HasAnnotation("ProductVersion", "3.0.0-preview5.19227.1");

            modelBuilder.Entity<RepairOrder>(entity =>
            {
                entity.Property(e => e.ControlNumber)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(13)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Customer)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Make)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.ManagerNote)
                    .HasMaxLength(5000)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Model)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Stage)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.TechncicianNote)
                    .HasMaxLength(5000)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Technician)
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.VehicleLocation)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .HasMaxLength(50)
                    .IsUnicode(false);

                entity.Property(e => e.Vin)
                    .HasColumnName("VIN")
                    .HasMaxLength(20)
                    .IsUnicode(false);
            });
        }
    }
```

When I run the project, and click the link to the new page, it shows "loading..." but never grabs the data from the database and loads the table.

Can someone point me in the right direction as to what I maybe missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because your url is wrong. You use

"api/RepairOrder/Index" instead of "api/Employee/Index"

There might be other problems with this app, but this is the first my weak eyes noticed.

Note:

- This app is ancient. Almost pre-history. It was composed even before I heard of Blazor.
- You should have used tools such as postman or Fiddler to verify whether your Web API returns data. This could save you lots of troubles.
- I'd advise you not to learn Blazor by following the articles and books composed by this guy. He himself needs lots of courses in Blazor and how the Internet works. He also never seriously goes beyond CRUD. The article you provided a link to is full of mistakes and basic understanding of the web, of SPA and of Blazor itself.

Learn instead:

1. Blazor Documents
2. I've started learning Blazor and recommend you to use

   - https://chrissainty.com/blazor/
   - https://learn-blazor.com/
     This is an excellent source of learning. Was deserted by its owner for a while. But I hope he has started to update it.
3. https://github.com/dotnet-presentations/blazor-workshop
4. https://github.com/aspnet/samples/tree/master/samples/aspnetcore/blazor

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thank you, your links pointed me to better options.  I have this issue figured out now!